# How can I configure a little server in Swift?

Tags: swift, server, swift4

I'm trying to make a rock, paper, scissors game for Swift and I program it without any problems but I would like to make it multiplayer in a P2P way or with a server, I don't care. I just want a little server to match players between them and the server just get if they choose paper or rock... But I do not have any knowledge about servers so do you have any tutorials about to implement a little server to make things like that in swift?
When I got this, I would like to make a database with the wins, draws and loses of each player. I know a little of SQL, so I could work with suggestions in that direction.

Comment: Firebase is also a good choice here.

Comment: You definitely want to use Firebase for this.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's [GameKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit) framework will give you the tools you need without the hassle of creating any sort of server. One of the main goals of GameKit is to enable multi-player interaction, but you'll also get other useful tools like player discovery, leaderboards, etc.

Comment: hah. Never knew of that! So it also provides you with a server?

Comment: Apple provides a GameCenter service that does the matchmaking, leaderboards, etc. Interaction during a game is peer-to-peer between devices, with one device hosting the game.

Answer (score 0):

There are some frameworks you can use for server - side development in Swift. The most common ones are Vapor and Kitura. You can see an article comparing them in this Ray Wenderlich link. https://www.raywenderlich.com/1323930-vapor-vs-kitura-choosing-a-server-side-swift-framework

Comment: Thanks for your help, which knowledge do I need to use Vapor or Kitura?

Comment: You want to use an existing BAAS for this, Guillermo.  It is 5 minutes work with Firebase.  (You could also use, say, PubNub.)

Answer (score 0):

Look into Multipeer Connectivity. This YouTube clip is for a multiplayer tic tax toe but it’ll put you on the right track. https://youtu.be/JwqsbsyN3LA